# DSA signature verification in C do not match with signature verification in console. OpenSSL

Tags: c, console, openssl, sign, dsa

I wrote a code to sign a message that apparently works fine, it can sign a message with a DSA private key (512 bits), and verify it later with the respective public key (no problems here). I´m using Windows 7.

But,

If I want to verify the sign in the console, openssl command always returns: Verification Failure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl\dsa.h>
#include <openssl\engine.h>
#include <openssl\pem.h>

int main(){
    char privkey[] = {
        "-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        "MIH4AgEAAkEA3F41fxvcwGZeFxXg2v0/5SR+cxTizT25QugwZgrC7u2zQYTO1Qu0\n"
        "PPDKUrLxkaLzKsUEJbQ1DImnG/FxtRjH7QIVAOp+o1qPhOI4DtnvYS86ynTxhDcF\n"
        "AkAyKbiUxJigARuuVVlGn4emXOtrT+Al+gmKbbVFfkS62RhSZexQ9+mBLv0/1R8T\n"
        "k37AwuybnflijiPjLxB1ZL00AkA2DXjw+0PJOyrQfn2Q44uHyZMG2WfXqT7CIz26\n"
        "ZiIAHDOkZQhOvPLqCKAXfwHgGrgl2JLovhVY8nPMdNk2vJijAhUAzK9TuVobhOE8\n"
        "kU0xl8lqaI/PMyg=\n"
        "-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
        };

    char pubkey[] = {
        "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
        "MIHwMIGoBgcqhkjOOAQBMIGcAkEA3F41fxvcwGZeFxXg2v0/5SR+cxTizT25Qugw\n"
        "ZgrC7u2zQYTO1Qu0PPDKUrLxkaLzKsUEJbQ1DImnG/FxtRjH7QIVAOp+o1qPhOI4\n"
        "DtnvYS86ynTxhDcFAkAyKbiUxJigARuuVVlGn4emXOtrT+Al+gmKbbVFfkS62RhS\n"
        "ZexQ9+mBLv0/1R8Tk37AwuybnflijiPjLxB1ZL00A0MAAkA2DXjw+0PJOyrQfn2Q\n"
        "44uHyZMG2WfXqT7CIz26ZiIAHDOkZQhOvPLqCKAXfwHgGrgl2JLovhVY8nPMdNk2\n"
        "vJij\n"
        "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
        };
        
    char message[] = {"Hello World!"};

    //save message for console test
    FILE *message_file = fopen ("message.txt","w");
    fwrite(message, strlen(message), 1, message_file);
    fclose(message_file);

    //save private key for console test
    FILE *privkey_file = fopen ("privkey.pem","w");
    fwrite(privkey, strlen(privkey), 1, privkey_file);
    fclose(privkey_file);

    //save public key for console test
    FILE *pubkey_file = fopen ("pubkey.pem","w");
    fwrite(pubkey, strlen(pubkey), 1, pubkey_file);
    fclose(pubkey_file);

    //Prepare sign  -----------------------------------------------------

    BIO *priv_bio;
    priv_bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(privkey, -1); 
    if(priv_bio == NULL){ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);return 1;}

    DSA *private_key;
    private_key = PEM_read_bio_DSAPrivateKey(priv_bio, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
    if(private_key == NULL){ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);return 2;} 

    unsigned int result, sign_length;
    unsigned char signature[1000] = {0};

    //generate sign
    result = DSA_sign(NULL, (const unsigned char*)message, strlen(message),
                    (unsigned char*)signature, &sign_length, private_key);
   
    if(result!=1){ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);return 3;}
    
    //save signature for console test
    FILE *sign_file = fopen ("signature","wb");
    fwrite((void*)signature, sign_length, 1, sign_file);
    fclose(sign_file);

    //verify sign  -----------------------------------------------------

    BIO *pub_bio;
    pub_bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(pubkey, -1); 
    if(pub_bio == NULL){ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);return 4;} 
   
    DSA *public_key;
    public_key = PEM_read_bio_DSA_PUBKEY(pub_bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(public_key == NULL){ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);return 5;} 

    result = DSA_verify(NULL, (const unsigned char*)message, strlen(message),
                        signature, sign_length, public_key);

    if(result>0){
        printf("Verification OK\n");
    }else{
        printf("Verification Failure. Error = %i\n",result);
    }

    BIO_free_all(priv_bio);
    DSA_free(private_key);
    DSA_free(public_key);
    
    //Console verification
    system("openssl dgst -verify pubkey.pem -signature signature message.txt");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Verification OK
Verification Failure
```

---

## Solved:

Apply SHA1 to the digest (message) before DSA_sign, **and**
apply SHA1 to the digest (message) before DSA_verify.

This makes compatible the signature to work in console with OpenSSL.

Comment: Don't add a solution by editing the question.  Instead, please add an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: The user is not active anymore so he will not accept the answer anyway, but the solution needed some visibility

Answer (score -1):

To use DSA with openssl you must pass in the `-dss1` to the dgst, otherwise it will use SHA1. Try this:

```
system("openssl dgst -dss1 -verify pubkey.pem -signature signature message.txt");
```

Comment: Adding "ab" in the command line does not have effect. Apparently still applies SHA1 to digest. But, I solved the problem, applying SHA1 to the digest just before generating the signature. It is also necessary to apply SHA1 to the digest to verify its signature.

Comment: Ups, I meant "-dss1" not "ab", I was thinking of something else  :-)